# DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy Vs RoundRobinPolicy

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am confused between DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy Vs RoundRobinPolicy

As per documentation, DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy first contact the nodes from local DC & later from Remote DC.

If I don't set withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc & allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel. 
Will all java client applications still will go to Remote DC in case of fallback??

I was currently using below code:

```
    DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().withLocalDc(cassandraConfig.getLocalDC())
.withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(cassandraConfig.getUsedHostsPerRemoteDc())
.allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel();
```

I got a problem while I am adding new DCs in my current Production cluster. Because of above code I can see Reads/Writes started on Remote DC as well which I am just adding up. Although New DCs are not having any Replication Factor set for them. Still I could see this traffic. Because Rebuilding of new nodes will take hours to finish i could not let all the applications to reach new nodes.
Finally I need to decommission new nodes to stop this behavior temporarily.

After Removing **withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc** & **allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel** all looks good.

Also Datastax Documentation says https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.Builder.html#allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel--

> It is however inadvisable to do so in almost all cases, as this would
>   potentially break consistency guarantees

If above is true then what is the use of DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy why RoundRobinPolicy was not good???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy` will not go to the remote DC until the options you mentioned are set. But this will happen only for consistency levels `LOCAL_ONE` & `LOCAL_QUORUM`. If you use non-`LOCAL_` consistency levels, then requests could be sent to the remote DC as well. But it should happen only for `QUORUM`, `EACH_QUORUM`, or when:

> this policy guarantees that no host in a remote data center will be queried unless no host in the local data center can be reached.

Although it's very strange to see that because you said:

> Although New DCs are not having any Replication Factor set for them.

I would recommend to check via JMX is it really reaching the your tables in remote DC?

Comment: I have edited the code shown above to fix & removed   .allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel(); I tried again & i could still see the same issues in our prod cluster. I am thinking maybe the issue is because of .withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(2) . Still very strange that NO RF is set for new DC. I could see some WARN first in client application & later ERROR: --

Comment: 2018-10-30 16:17:44.853 WARN   [prod cluster-nio-worker-10 - HostConnectionPool] Error creating connection to /x.y.z.141:9042
2018-10-30 16:17:46.460 ERROR  [prod cluster-reconnection-0 - AbstractReconnectionHandler] Authentication error on host /x.y.z.141:9042: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE

Comment: 2018-10-30 16:17:46.462 ERROR  [prod cluster-reconnection-0 - Cluster] Authentication error during reconnection to /x.y.z.141:9042, scheduling retry in 2000 milliseconds
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /x.y.z.141:9042: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE

Comment: Have you changed replication for authentication keyspaces? https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secSystemKeyspace.html I recommend to leave only  `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().withLocalDc(cassandraConfig.getLocalDC())` and have contact points only from local DC in the cluster config

Comment: I have used the same code as said in my above comment, after my testing it seems it is just a noise of logs in client applications that not able to connect to new node. & Later Authentication error while making connection on new node. Despite functionality is working fine in all Client applications as we are only using LOCAL_QUORUM CL in all client apps.

Comment: This  actually proves DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy is aware of any new DC getting into the cluster & throwing the logs until we fix Replication Factor in system_auth keyspace. If we are using LocalDC & it's contact points in connection. Applications will run fine until we are on LOCAL_ONE or LOCAL_QUORUM.

Comment: authentication error may happen if you changed replciation and didn't repair yet. Also, the data for `cassandra` user are read with `QUORUM`, so if you're using it to authenticate, it's better to create a separate user

Comment: it's better to change from using it - it's better to create a separate user for application: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/unifiedAuth/chgDefaultSuperuser.html